How can I properly read data from the partitioned Athena table?
I'm trying to read data using a partitioned Athena table for a file uploaded to S3. I uploaded a Parquet file to S3 and created an Athena table with partitions. I used the storage.location.template property with hash routing. However, when I run a query in the Athena query editor, the result is empty.
What I did:

Uploaded a Parquet file to AWS S3:
s3://prod1/dev/data/hash_result.parquet


Created a table in AWS Athena with the following query:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `prod1`(
  `_id` string, 
  `product_id0` int, 
  `product_id1` int, 
  `similarity` double)
PARTITIONED BY (similarity_range STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://prod1/dev/data/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'parquet.compression'='SNAPPY',
  'projection.enabled'='true',
  'projection.similarity_range.type'='enum',
  'projection.similarity_range.values'='0.0-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.6,0.6-0.8,0.8-1.0',
  'projection.similarity_range.enabled'='true',
  'storage.location.template'='s3://prod1/dev/data/hash_result.parquet#${similarity_range}'
 );

Then ran:
MSCK REPAIR TABLE prod1;


Executed a SELECT query:
SELECT * FROM prod1 LIMIT 10;



Issue:
The query returns no results, even though the Parquet file contains data.
Question:

Why is the query returning empty results?
How can I properly read data from the partitioned Athena table?

